# Git - 'Your branch is ahead of "X" by "X" commits.'

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal

I'm working on a project alone, it has two branches: main and deployment.

Here is a rundown of the commands i'm running and messages im receiving back in terminal.


**On branch deployment**: git status

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/deployment' by 13 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)


nothing to commit, working tree clean'


**On branch deployment**: git push https://github.com/name

Everything up-to-date


**On branch deployment**: git status

On branch deployment
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/deployment' by 13 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)


nothing to commit, working tree clean'


**On branch deployment**: git checkout main

main

Switched to branch 'main'

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)


**On branch main**: git push https://github.com/name

Everything up-to-date


**On branch main**: git status

On branch main

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)


nothing to commit, working tree clean

So i got this git history after i merged main with deployment and did a push to github. no errors everything pushed. Insertions and deletions all were applied to the live site. 

My history as you can see is showing i have changes to push still but when i do push nothing gets pushed and if i run git status after it says i still have changes to push.


what in tarnations is going on ?


running git remote -v

both (fetch) and (push) origins match 


running git fetch 

76373fb...22b0csd main -> origin/main

019287b...22b0csd deployment -> origin/deployment

Comment: Run `git remote -v` and look at the results to see that the `origin` (for both `fetch` and `push`) matches https://github.com/name  ?

Comment: after running git remote -v both (fetch) and (push) origins match

Comment: and you've run `git fetch` to make sure your local origin/branches are up-to-date?

Comment: after running git fetch i think what im seeing is two different commits pointing to the same commit looks like this 83217fb...22b0csd first set of numbers are different second set are same. see post for edits

Comment: Note that `git push` does what Git calls *opportunistic updates* to remote-tracking names like `origin/main`. Running `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` will do a single, all-at-once update of *all* of your remote-tracking names, eliminating the need to opportunistically update one name at a time. Also, some very ancient versions of Git (that are nonetheless still in use) are bad about some kinds of updates; running `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` convinces them to update correctly. This was all fixed by Git version 1.9, but if your Git is older than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st question:

> Git - 'Your branch is ahead of “X” by “X” commits.'

This is a common message: it's usually nothing to worry about.

2nd question:

> My history as you can see is showing i have changes to push still but
> when i do push nothing gets pushed and if i run git status after it
> says i still have changes to push.

Please run `git fetch`.

Personally, I usually run `git pull --all`

Here's a good discussion:

[Git Fetch vs Pull: What's the Difference Between the Git Fetch and Git Pull Commands?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-fetch-vs-pull/)

Comment: after running git fetch and checking git status on both branches its saying both branches are up to date, nothing to commit. Why even is this though? so fetch brings the remotes data to my local copy but my local copy is the latest version so why do i need to fetch in the first place? And what causes this ive never ran into this problem before

Comment: Short answer: that's the way Git works :)  Longer answer: run `git log` on each of the branches ("master" and "deployment") and each of the repos ("remote" and "local") until you're confident "everything's OK".  STRONG SUGGESTION: If you haven't already, get a "GUI" Git client to analyze your branch history. If you're on Windows, I'd suggest either [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and/or [Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org/download/).  I use both :)

Comment: @Colinthedev1: obviously, in at least that one case, your local copy *wasn't* up to date with the other (remote) Git, in that you had the same commits they did, but your Git was *not yet aware* that they had the same commits. The `git fetch` operation has your Git (your software talking to your repository) connect to their Git and synchronize your Git's knowledge of what their status is, while also picking up any new commits. If they never have any new commits, that's fine, but you're still getting the synchronization: your Git now *knows* about theirs.

Comment: @paulsm4: I'd avoid `git pull --all`. (Well, I generally avoid `git pull` entirely, but that's not what I mean here.) The `--all` option is simply passed to `git fetch`, where it means *all remotes*. That's an odd thing to do with `git pull` since the *second* command that `git pull` will run will use only *one* commit hash ID, obtained from *one* remote.